# Prime Reflections

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, twin-primes

How would you describe the following pattern?:

For each primorial from 30 onward, there exists a pattern in the arrangement of the prime factors of the composite numbers which I call "the mirror patterns". For each of these mirror patterns, there is a set of five whole numbers to which I have assigned the names $Zero$, $the$ $Left$ $Mirror$ $Center$, $the$ $Central$ $Number$, $the$ $Right$ $Mirror$ $Center$, and $the$ $Product$. Here is the set of these five whole numbers for the primorial 30: $$0,4,15,26,30$$
Surrounding 4 are the prime numbers 3 and 5.

Surrounding 26 are the prime factors 5 and 3.

$$15=3·5$$

Comment: Law of small numbers?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I used small numbers in the example. There exists such a pattern for every primorial. The next example is with 210: 0…5,6,7…105…203,204,205…210 It is not only a law for small numbers, but for all whole numbers.

Comment: What would this pattern look like for 210?

Comment: @MarkFischler: See that 0+210=210 and that one half of 210, which is 105, is centered between 0 and 210. To the left and to the right of 105 are the "mirror centers" 6 and 204, which sum to 210. 6 is surrounded by 5 and 7. 204 has 7 and 5 as factors around it. 203 is divisible by 7 and 205 is divisible by 5. Notice that the prime factors 5 and 7 around 204 are in reverse order from the way they are around 6.

Comment: @JeffreyYoung And what is the property of $105$ that corresponds to $15=3\cdot 5$? And for $2320$ there is no number surrounded by $7$ and $11$, so?

Comment: Of course, if $q$ is a prime $\le p$, then $q$ divides $p\#-q$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Take your time and examine the patterns carefully. 105=3·5·7. As for the primorial 2310, look at 120 and 2190. 119 is divisible by 7. 121 is divisible by 11. 2189 is divisible by 11. 2191 is divisible by 7.

Comment: @JeffreyYoung Why $120$ and not $43$ or $197$?  I presume because $120$ is divisible by $3$ and $5$.  That would make it just a basic artifact of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem.  In fact there is nothing special about primorials here; you could replace the primes with any sequence of relatively prime integers.

Comment: @ErickWong: My reasons would be different questions.

Comment: @JeffreyYoung "Why $120$?" is entirely relevant to this question.  You asked us to suggest a description for "Left Mirror Center", but none of your examples serve to pin down what you mean.  Just saying "$119$ is divisible by $7$ and $121$ is divisible by $11$" is not enough, because $42$ is divisible by $7$ and $44$ is divisible by $11$.  So I repeat, why not $43$ (and its mirror pair $2267$)?

Comment: @ErickWong: 7 less and 7 more than 120 and 2190. These are the points where the difference of 14 is (ignoring prime factors > 11). Let 1 through 2310 each be the first term of an arithmetic progression with common difference of 2310. 2,3,5,7, and 11 cannot produce a difference > 14 between consecutive primes.