# If $q$ is a prime $\leq p$, then $q$ divides $p\# − q$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, prime-factorization

If $q$ is a prime $\leq p$, then $q$ divides $p\# − q$

What does this mean?

I know that it is related to something which I have been studying, but what does $p\# − q$ mean? I am only beginning to learn about this notation.

Comment: Where did you see it?

Comment: @MJD: In the comments here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963909/prime-reflections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $p\#$ is sometimes used for the product of all the primes $\le p$.

Please see, for example, [this article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial_prime) For more, search using the key word *primorial*.

If $q\le p$, then $q$ is one of the primes that got multiplied together to form $p\#$. It follows that $q$ divides $p\#$, and therefore $q$ divides $p\#-q$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
If André Nicolas' meaning
for $p\#$
is correct,
and $q$ is a prime
such that
$q \le p$,
do you see why
$q | p\#$?

Then the stated result should be clear.